# I need to create an array that indexes each line of text as a new index. C#/Xamarin/Android

Tags: c#, android, arrays, listview, xamarin

I have a text file with 7000+ lines in it(in list form). I need to create an array that changes each line into a new index so that I can add checkboxes next to each item. (Which will then print to a .txt file if checked.)

I have found a few articles about how to do this but none of them really answered my question.
I honestly don't even know where to begin turning it into an array.
Please let me know what information you need to assist me.

Comment: Perhaps a better way of explaining it, I need to create a List to where each line of my text is a different ListItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a List object by reading a file and want to have each separate line as a list item, here is what you can do.

```
//File name
const string f = "TextFile1.txt";

// Declare new List.
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

// Use using StreamReader for disposing.
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    lines.Add(line);
    }
}
```

And then if you wish to convert this list into an array, you can use the  .ToArray() method of the List object.

```
    string[] arrayOfLines = lines.ToArray();
```

I hope i got your question correctly and this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Perfect answer. I don't mean to be a noob and all, but could you please explain to me how to make the list into a CheckBoxList once I have it populated? Thanks so much.

Comment: Consider the List object "lines" in the above sample. 
Create an object of the CheckedBoxList. and iterate through your list adding each item as follows. 

foreach (string line in lines) 
{
    checkedListBox.Items.Add(line);
}

This will directly add a list item entry from a list<string> to a CheckedBoxList. Add them one by one into the check box list. Hope that works. 
If the answer helped you, don't forget to mark it or vote up.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filename = @"C:\Example\existingfile.txt";
var lines = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream) lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

You can then iterate over the `List` like an array.

Answer (score 0):

If your List is stored in a String you could try it the following way:

```
String largeList; 
String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

String[] lines = largeList.split(nl);
```

Lines contains now every line accessible by lines[x] -> x is the row number